# FindTypeMapFor method not exists in AutoMapper 11

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0, automapper-11

I am currently upgrading a web API that was developed on NET Core 5.0 and upgrading it to NET Core 6.0. When upgrading the NuGet AutoMapper package to version 11.0.1, I find that the FindTypeMapFor method does not exist in the ConfigurationProvider definition.

```
public Dictionary<string, PropertyMappingValue> GetPropertyMappingFromAutomapper<TSource, TDestination>(List<string> reverseOrderProperties) where TSource : class where TDestination : class
    {
        Dictionary<string, PropertyMappingValue> dictionaryPropertyMapping = new(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        if (typeof(TSource).Equals(typeof(ForNotIncludeDto)) || typeof(TSource).Equals(typeof(ForNotSortingDto)) || typeof(TSource).Equals(typeof(ForNotDistinctDto)))
        {
            return dictionaryPropertyMapping;
        }

        TypeMap typeMap = this.Mapper.ConfigurationProvider.FindTypeMapFor<TSource, TDestination>();

        if (typeMap is null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Cannot find exact property mapping instance " + $"for <{typeof(TSource)},{typeof(TDestination)}>");
        }

        List<PropertyMap> propertyMaps = typeMap.PropertyMaps.Where(x => x.Ignored == false).ToList();
        List<PathMap> pathMaps = typeMap.PathMaps.Where(x => x.Ignored == false).ToList();

        foreach (MemberInfo member in typeMap.SourceTypeDetails.AllMembers)
        {
            List<string> originPropertyMap = propertyMaps.Where(x => x.SourceMember is not null && x.SourceMember.Name.Equals(member.Name)).Select(x => x.DestinationName).ToList();

            if (originPropertyMap.Count.Equals(0))
            {
                originPropertyMap = pathMaps.Where(x => x.SourceMember is not null && x.SourceMember.Name.Equals(member.Name)).Select(x => x.DestinationName).ToList();
            }

            if (originPropertyMap.Count > 0)
            {
                dictionaryPropertyMapping.Add(member.Name, new PropertyMappingValue(originPropertyMap, reverseOrderProperties.Where(x => x.Equals(member.Name)).Any()));
            }
        }

        return dictionaryPropertyMapping;
    }
```

How can I get the TypeMap object of a specific mapping?

How can I use FindTypeMapFor or some method that will replace it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that method?

Comment: Check if there is a mapping for **TSource** and **TDestination**, then get the property mapping. `List<PropertyMap> propertyMaps = typeMap.PropertyMaps.Where(x => x.Ignored == false).ToList();`

Comment: Yes, but why are you touching AM's internal data?

Comment: To return a dictionary with the mapping of priorities and thus verify if there is a mapping between the DTO -> TDestination and the Entity -> TSource; For example, in the API request the client requests to order the information by a property of the DTO, that query is taken to the database and the mapping between the DTO and the Entity allows me to know that property A in the DTO corresponds to Property C of the Entity.

Comment: You should look into expression mapping.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Please could you help me understand better with an example, thanks.

Comment: Check the docs and the examples in the [repo](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping/search?q=orderby).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu My use case for `FindTypeMapFor`: given a `List<object>`, identify and map those elements that can be mapped to type `T` in the more elegant way than trying it and catching `AutoMapperMappingException`.

Answer (score 14):

This was moved to the "Internal" object on AutoMapper 11.

Here's the new usage:

```cs
using AutoMapper.Internal;

Mapper.ConfigurationProvider.Internal().FindTypeMapFor
```

Comment: Doesn't work. ConfigurationProvider is not a static field.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Automapper v12.0.1, try using the following code.

```
using AutoMapper.Internal;
...
var internalAPI = InternalApi.Internal(configInstance);
var map = internalAPI.FindTypeMapFor(source.GetType(), destination.GetType());
```

Comment: This is just a more verbose way to write the code above. So maybe just upvote that one instead? :)